# Getting warning message in statistics module

Tags: 6

Below is the warning message. I'm getting this message sometimes and I'm using Drupal 6.

> user warning: Table './ri5_r3/accesslog' is marked as crashed and
>   should be repaired query: DELETE FROM accesslog WHERE timestamp <
>   1376371846 in
>   /home/ri5/public_html/modules/statistics/statistics.module
>   on line 189.

not sure what to do, what is the proper way to solve this issue ?

Comment: Fyi, slightly irrelevant comment regarding statistics module effeciency: http://drupalize.me/videos/overview-performance-scalability. It is suggested to switch to google analytics :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in **phpMyAdmin** solved my problem.

> 1. Login to phpMyAdmin
> 2. Choose the affected database. If you only have one database, it
>      should choose it by default so you don't need to do anything.
> 3. In the main panel, you should see a list of your database tables.
>      Check the boxes by the tables that need repair.
> 4. At the bottom of the window just below the list of tables, there is
>      a drop down menu. Choose "Repair Table"

This should fix your table, and let you access it again. Now that it is fixed... it's a good idea to make that database backup!

taken from this [source](http://php.about.com/od/mysqladministration/qt/repair_mysql.htm)